# Get object function using reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I know how to get the properties using reflection but how would you get the function name and type of a property:

For Example: Combobox.Items.Add

I would like to get the info. for "Add" with reflection. Is this possible in .Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Reflection to get a MethodInfo object that describes the method:

```
MethodInfo[] method = Combobox.Items.GetType().GetMethods();
```

Once you have this, you can use the methods and properties of [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx)
 to access and view information about the method.

To get the parameters that this method receives:

```
        MethodInfo[] method = Combobox.Items.GetType().GetMethods();

       // equivalent to previous code.
       // MethodInfo[] method = typeof(ObjectCollection).GetMethods();

        MethodInfo someMethod = method[0];

        ParameterInfo[] parameters = someMethod.GetParameters();
```

Comment: Since method is an array of MethodInfo the last line for getting params won't work...

Comment: @liortal Thanks. What i am trying to accomplish is creating a limited intellisense for a business logic application. By limited I mean not giving them the overwhelming list of members, just the ones needed for the app.

Comment: I see, good luck. Just remember that Reflection is an expensive mechanism that is not recommended to be used in time-critical areas of your application (where UI responsiveness is needed for example). For these areas, it is preferrable to "cache" the values on the application startup if possible, and then store them somewhere to be retrieved later.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to get the info. for "Add" with reflection. Is this possible in .Net?

Yes.

Just use `Type.GetMethod`. So, here you'd have to say:

```
var addMethodInfo = typeof(ObjectCollection).GetMethod("Add");
```

I'm using the fact that `ComboBox.Items` is of type `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection`.

Comment: @tmax: Please clarify what you mean. `Add` is a method. It doesn't have members.

Comment: Do you mean parameters? `var addMethodInfo = typeof(ObjectCollection).GetMethod("Add").GetParameters();`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all methods of a given object try

```
MethodInfo[] MI = Combobox.Items.GetType().GetMethods ();
// you can then loop over MI and access the method name for example MI[0].Name or even Invoke the method etc.
```